# how to set opera to highlight images on webpages?

Tags: opera-10

This is really the problem when I'm using opera browser. I'm fond of backing up articles that I want to ms word(by copy pasting and save as pdf) because I believe that websites don't really last long.
How can I enable opera to highlight images as well, because if you have already used opera for highlighting web pages you should have notice that it doesn't highlight images.

Comment: You mean when you "Select All"?

Comment: not really, just the relevant one. Because there are lots of advertismnts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: you can't.

however, there is a workaround being discussed here:

**[Dealbreaker: Opera Copy And Paste Does Text Only](http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=285592)**

*... but i couldn't get it to work in Opera 10.*